# Insert query not doing anything

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

As the title suggests I'm trying to create a mysqli insert query to insert data from a form into a table.The table structure is split into 4 columns as follows:

1) PO (auto incrementing int *primary key*)

2) Job Name (VARCHAR)

3) Date (VARCHAR)

4) Address (VARCHAR)

With the current code I am getting no errors when i submit, but rather just no results whatsoever. I'm rather confused as to what part of this doesn't work and looking for some insight into it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<?php
require 'classes/Mysql.php';
$conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die('There was a problem        connecting to the database');


if($_POST && !empty($jobname) && !empty($date)){
    $jobname = $_POST['jobname'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$query = "INSERT INTO 'po_10152796'('Job Name', 'Date', 'Address') VALUES ('$jobname',' $date',' $address')";
mysqli_query($conn,$query);

}

?>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>New Job - Tradeflow</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>
<h2>Your PO will be provided when the form is completed, fields marked with an asterix (*) are required and must be filled out in order to submit.</h2>
<form id="newJobForm" method="post" class="form-newJob" role="form" action="">
<div class = "relative">
  <label>Job Name: </label>
  <input class="blueinput" name="jobname" input type="text" placeholder="Job Name"/>
  </div>
  <div class="relative">
  <label>Date: </label>
  <input class="blueinput" name="date" input type="datetime" placeholder="" />
  </div>
  <div class="relative">
  <label>Address: </label>
  <input class="blueinput" name="address" input type="text" placeholder="Address" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="bluebutton" aligh="left"  value="Submit" />



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you check for errors to find out there are no errors?

Comment: If you did, mysql would have mentioned that quotes cannot be used around table or field names. Hence your query has syntax errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if condition of checking submit forms is wrong. Your if condition would return error. Try this:

```
if(!empty($_POST["jobname"]) && !empty($_POST["date"])){
```

For your query, don't use single tick(`'`) for your table name and column name, and use backticks (`) instead.

```
"INSERT INTO `po_10152796` (`Job Name`, `Date`, `Address`) VALUES ('$jobname',' $date',' $address')";
```

**Note: Please don't use space(s) for your Column Name.**

Your query is also prone to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), so I would recommend using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function atleast.

```
$jobname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["jobname"]);
```

For better security, use `mysqli_*` prepared statement or PDO. Here is an example of `mysqli_*` prepared statement:

```
if($stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO po_10152796 (Job_Name, Date, Address) VALUES(?,?,?)")){
  $stmt->bind_param("sss",$_POST["jobname"],$_POST["date"],$_POST["address"]);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Well spotted on that `if`

Comment: Wow right? One of those moments where my brain just didn't even think about looking at that! Thanks for that! And for the backtick thing, I just gotta get into practice, everyone keeps telling me to remember to do it but it just hasn't clicked yet! Thanks for taking the time out to help a newbie!

Answer (score 2):

Remove those quotes from your query with backticks

```
"INSERT INTO `po_10152796` (`Job Name`, `Date`, `Address`) VALUES ('$jobname',' $date',' $address')";
```

> Table names and column names are enclosed within `backticks` and its not compulsory unless and until the `table name` or `column name` is not `Reserve Keyword`

And you need to update your `if` condition too

```
if(!empty($_POST['jobname']) && !empty($_POST['date'])){
```

Answer (score 1):

You use single quotes for escaping column and table names. That is wrong. For escaping table names you have to use backticks. single quotes is only for string literals

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `po_10152796`(`Job Name`, `Date`, `Address`) VALUES ('$jobname',' $date',' $address')";
```

And also you have to check for errors after every sql statement.
Do not use blanks in column names. 
You should learn about prepared statement for preventing sql injection.